# Find out where a process writes to

Tags: python

Is there a way to find out which files a subprocess writes to and reads from?

Ideally I'd like to create some subprocess, wrap it in a function and then query that to see which files the subprocess touched:

```
p = sp.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=sp.PIPE)
wp = watch_files(p)
out, err = wp.communicate()

print wp.files_read(), wp.files_written()
```

The `watch_files` is what I'd like to implement. Any ideas if something like this exists or how to go about implementing it?

Comment: I guess `pdb` or `strace` (`strace -p <pid>`) will be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Unix, I'd start with `strace -fTt` and looking for `stat` or `open` syscalls.

You can probably trap the output from `strace` - by default `strace` prints to `STDERR`. You can have it 'save' it's output to a logfile with `-o`.

You might find there's some mileage in looking in `/proc/<pid>/fd` which shows *current* file descriptors (open files).

Comment: Good idea! Just out of curiosity, do you know how much `strace` slows down a process?

Comment: It does impose an overhead, so anything running 'straced' will be slower. How much slower is very much a question of what it does,  and how it does it. So it's impossible to say. I have not yet had a scenario where stracing a process has significantly slowed it, but I wouldn't routinely strace everything.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty vague question. I was looking for something like "a whole lot! on the level of valgrind" vs "just a little bit". In any case, I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: It's definitely not 'a whole lot' - most processes will run 'normally'. Just bear in mind every syscall they make will generate a log entry (either to STDOUT or disk) - so if they do a lot, they'll become io bound where they might not have been before.